# Interdependent objects modelling

Tags: java, android, networking, model

My (Android) app needs a network scanner feature.

I want to give it a subnet and I want it to send a request to each possible address on the subnet and determine whether or not it's responsive.

I have two classes:

- Device, which contains an address and a property `available` (bool) (that can be set by the method `checkAvailable`).
- NetworkerScanner, which extends `Thread` and instantiates all the `Device`s.
- Eventually, I plan to have an object that is an observer on an Observable collection that will contain all the available devices.

Adding the available Devices to the Collection is not obvious.

**Algorithm**

```
Let col be a Observable Collection
For each possible address
    Instantiate a corresponding Device
    On a new, separate thread, get this new device's availability. 
    If it's available, then add it to col.
```

Checking device's availability is not immediate (I'm using Volley, which uses callbacks).

How can I, from my HTTP request callback, add the Device to the collection?

I have several ideas:

- Pass a reference to the collection to the device when instantiating it, which seems like a bad idea, since the collection doesn't have a reason to be a property of the Device. More than that, if I wanted to run multiple scans on the same `Device` instances, it wouldn't work anymore since a `Device` could only have one Collection.
- I could also pass a reference to the collection to the `checkAvailable` method, but I feel like this is a trick (and a trick of the wrong type of tricks).
- When calling `checkAvailable`, pass a reference to an `onResponseListener` (the callback method for the HTTP request) to it. Since I would have created the listener in my `NetworkScanner`, I could capture the local collection. But I feel this is wrong. Like... very wrong.

Please suggest.

Comment: "_I want to give it a subnet and I want it to send a request to each possible address on the subnet and determine whether or not it's responsive._" That may be practical on an IPv4 `/24` network, but consider an IPv4 `/16` network with 65,534 possible hosts, or an IPv4 `/8` network with 16,777,214 possible hosts. Don't even consider a standard IPv6 `/64` network with 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible hosts that, at even 1,000,000 addresses per second would take over 584,542 years to scan.

Comment: That's true, though the app will be used with devices connected to the phone's access point, so it's not really a problem in my case.

Comment: That really doesn't mean anything. We have WAPs that have IPv6 `/64` networks and IPv4 `/16` networks because all the WAPs connect to WLCs to facilitate roaming. In fact, my company and others, now require any application to support IPv6, and you simply cannot scan every IPv6 address on a standard IPv6 network.

Comment: I'm talking about the Android AP... More than this, you're missing the point, this is a modelling question.